# How to read array out of struct?

Tags: c, struct

I have this C code:

```
struct ATAInfo* data;

data = (struct ATAInfo*)malloc(512);
```

Then I call a function, which fills the struct. This is a bit difficult to explain, because i call a function, making a syscall through an interrupt, which reads information form my cd-rom device. 
I call it this way:

```
ata_identify(0, data)
```

And the Function is defined like this:

```
bool ataIdentify(int device, struct ATAInfo *ataInfo){
```

Now i fill it with this:

```
uint16_t pointer = ataInfo;
uint16_t word;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    word = inw(DATA_PORT);
    *(uint16_t *) pointer = word;
    pointer ++;
}
```

Now I want to read one attribute out of the struct, which is declared like this:

```
uint8_t ModelNumber[40];
```

I did this:

```
printf("name: %s\n", data->ModelNumber);
```

But I get "name: (null)".

Comment: Should be: `data = malloc(sizeof(*data));`

Comment: Removed C++ tag (unless you want comments about how you should not use `malloc`, use `iostreams` instead of `printf`, etc. etc.).

Comment: Likely, the unexpected output "name: (null)" has to do with how the structure was initialized; perhaps associated with the functionion "which fills the struct".

Comment: Please show a minimal, compilable example that reproduces the problem. The behavior claimed should not even be possible - `ModelNumber` is an array member of the struct (not a pointer), so it can't be NULL.

Comment: Can you provide more information? i.e. 2 things: struct definition, and function definition for whatever function populates the member in question. ( Then I call a function, which fills the struct. ) Edit your post with these two, and answers will be more complete.

Comment: see my edit on the top

Comment: Are you sure your `malloc` call is **not** returning NULL? that is one way I _think_ printf would print `(null)` upon printint `ModelNumber`...

Comment: @Massa: How can I find out, if my malloc returns NULL?

Comment: substitute `printf("name: %s\n", data->ModelNumber);` for `if(data) { printf("name: %s\n", data->ModelNumber); } else { printf("malloc returned null, something is amiss...\n"); }` Ah, try to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (also known as a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/))

Comment: i dont get zero i get: 0x32056

Answer (score 1):

This block of code does not seem right:

```
uint16_t pointer = ataInfo;
uint16_t word;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    word = inw(DATA_PORT);
    *(uint16_t *) pointer = word;
    pointer ++;
}
```

Did you mean:

```
uint16_t* pointer = (unit16_t*)ataInfo;
uint16_t word;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
{
    word = inw(DATA_PORT);
    *pointer = word;
    pointer ++;
}
```

Comment: oh yes, thank you. But sadly it doesn't work either.